# How to do query autocompletion/suggestions with multi-word search?

Tags: zend-framework, search, autocomplete, lucene

I am working with a web site using zend framework. I need to use zend lucene in to my site. We have an option for the user to search for category, items, etc.

We are using zend lucene with auto complete option. Let's say I have items like 'iphone 3s' ,'iphone 4s','iphone 5s'. If user types 'iph' i am getting search results  'iphone 3s', 'iphone 4s', 'iphone 5s'. Currently I am getting good results for single word searches.

I had used the combination of different query construction APIs for different searches.

For single word searches i am using `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard` and I am getting matched pattern results perfectly. For multi term
searches I used `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm()`, but I am getting results only in the case of exact text searches. Some one please 
help me integrate this feature?

I am getting good results by using `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard` for single terms and I need the same kind of perfection for multi term search. Because `Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm()` returns good results only in the case of exact search text, I can't use the auto complete option.

My code for search section below:

```
$searchfield = $searchtype."_name";//Like category_name
$searchfieldid = $searchtype."_id";//Like category_name
$res_table = "t_".$searchtype;  
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(Zend_Registry::get('_datapath'));

/* Here we used different API for creating query for diffrent pattern
    1) Words < 3 chars(it wont work in wild cart
    2) Single word (pattern matching--wildcard)
    3) More than one word serach
*/
$res = explode(' ',$searchkey);
if(strlen($searchkey) <3) /*if key >=3 then only wildcard search works*/
{
    $term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($searchkey, $searchfield);
    $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($term);
}
else if(sizeof($res)==1) /*write condition for single word -->check sub str count*/
{   
    $searchkey1 = $searchkey."*";//car*
    $pattern = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($searchkey1, $searchfield);
    $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard($pattern);
}
else
{ /*if more than one word comes use different query rather than wildcard query search*/
    $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
    foreach($res as $key => $val)
    {
        /*  TRUE is used to define required term.
            FALSE is used to define prohibited term.
            NULL is used to define a term that is neither required nor prohibited.
            (here we  used last term as null and others are true*/
        if($key == (sizeof($res)-1))
            $signs = null;/*Last item is not a mandatory, so use null*/
        else
            $signs = true;
        $query->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($val,$searchfield), $signs);
    }
}   
$hits = $index->find($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

After long search I got solution. For using applications like auto complete we can use wildcard queries and boolean queries. 
If a search text contain single word it always work with wildcard queries[provided search text contains minimum 3 characters exists] But in case my search term having <  3 characters wildcard query api wont works. So I modified the code on \library\Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\Query\Wildcard.php  on line 65.
    private static $_minPrefixLength = 1;[initially it was 3 now i changed the limit].

Also for multi word searches I had split the words using space and created independent wildcard query  for each word and using the boolean(and) query api I joined the query from the wildcard api. It works for me. My code given below:
[My humble request if my code useful for anybody please vote for me]

```
            $index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open(Zend_Registry::get('_datapath'));

            $res                 =  explode(' ',$searchkey);            
            $query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
            foreach($res as $key    => $val)
            {
                if(strlen($val)>0)//for wildcard queries atleast 1 items required
                {
                    $searchkey1         = $val."*";//car*
                    $pattern            = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($searchkey1, $searchfield);
                    $userQuery          = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard($pattern);
                    $signs              = true;                     
                    $query->addSubquery($userQuery, $signs /* required */);
                }           

            }

        $hits       = $index->find($query);
```

Comment: It is good explained. I am not using it for now, but for my site, i will be implementing a search using Lucene. Currently i am working on autocomplete for my zend site and may be will try your way. Thanks for good share

Comment: Although *I haven't tested that myself*, I discourage to amend the 'min 3 letters' limit. I suppose it is there to prevent too much workload to the server, so if you could avoid that. I have instead loaded some simple data used for 1 and 2 letters autocompletion/suggestion (as I can provide simple light samples in my case), and from 3 letters, the webpage requests the server.